# Please advice simple module for sending plain-text emails on nodejs using exim

Tags: node.js, email, plaintext, exim4

I have vitual machine, with exim4 installed, and I want to send plain-text emails from my project, working under node.js.

I have googled around and found very nice solution - [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer), but it is too heavy for me. I really do not want anything heavy. Could you please advice some light solutions please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) might be the light solution you are looking for